# Question regarding javafx.fxml.LoadException: error

Tags: java, javafx

I'm facing this error when I run [this](https://github.com/pdeitel/JavaHowToProgram11e_EarlyObjects/tree/master/examples/ch01/Painter) JavaFX painter project. I think this exception occurs when the `FXMLLoader` class cannot find the class `PainterController`, which is defined in the FXML file `Painter.fxml.

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/malek/eclipse-workspace/testLab/bin/application/Painter.fxml:13

    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:935)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:983)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:757)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2853)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3376)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3332)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3300)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3272)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3248)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3241)
    at testLab/application.Painter.start(Painter.java:15)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@20/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PainterController
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at javafx.fxml@20/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:933)
    ... 22 more
```

**Here is my Painter.java:**

```
package application;
    
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Painter extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        try {
            Parent root =
                    FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Painter.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root); // attach scene graph to scene
            stage.setTitle("Painter"); // displayed in window's title bar
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show(); // display the stage
            // attach scene to stage
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

here is my Painter.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<TitledPane animated="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="480.0" prefWidth="640.0" text="dadasda" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" fx:controller="PainterController">
   <content>
      <BorderPane>
         <left>
            <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="-Infinity" spacing="8.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="8.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
               <children>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" text="Drawing Color">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="142.0" prefWidth="153.0">
                           <children>
                              <VBox layoutX="1.0" layoutY="-2.0" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" spacing="8.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <RadioButton id="blackRadioButton" fx:id="blackRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#colorRadioButtonSelected" text="Black">
                                       <toggleGroup>
                                          <ToggleGroup fx:id="colorToggleGroup" />
                                       </toggleGroup>
                                    </RadioButton>
                                    <RadioButton id="redRadioButton" fx:id="redRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#colorRadioButtonSelected" text="Red" toggleGroup="$colorToggleGroup" />
                                    <RadioButton fx:id="greenRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#colorRadioButtonSelected" text="Green" toggleGroup="$colorToggleGroup" />
                                    <RadioButton fx:id="blueRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#colorRadioButtonSelected" text="Blue" toggleGroup="$colorToggleGroup" />
                                 </children>
                              </VBox>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                  </TitledPane>
                  <TitledPane animated="false" text="Pen Size">
                    <content>
                      <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="104.0" prefWidth="153.0">
                           <children>
                              <VBox maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" spacing="8.0">
                                 <children>
                                    <RadioButton fx:id="smallRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sizeRadioButtonSelected" text="Small">
                                       <toggleGroup>
                                          <ToggleGroup fx:id="sizeToggleGroup" />
                                       </toggleGroup>
                                    </RadioButton>
                                    <RadioButton fx:id="mediumRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sizeRadioButtonSelected" text="Medium" toggleGroup="$sizeToggleGroup" />
                                    <RadioButton fx:id="largeRadioButton" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sizeRadioButtonSelected" text="Large" toggleGroup="$sizeToggleGroup" />
                                 </children>
                              </VBox>
                           </children>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </content>
                  </TitledPane>
                  <Button fx:id="undoButton" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#undoButtonPressed" prefHeight="29.0" prefWidth="155.0" text="Undo" />
                  <Button fx:id="clearButton" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#clearButtonPressed" text="Clear" />
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </left>
         <center>
            <Pane fx:id="drawingAreaPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" onMouseDragged="#drawingAreaMouseDragged" style="-fx-background-color: white;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets right="8.0" />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </Pane>
         </center>
         <padding>
            <Insets right="8.0" />
         </padding>
      </BorderPane>
   </content>
</TitledPane>
```

Here is my PainterController.java:

```
package application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.Paint;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

public class PainterController {
    private enum PenSize {
        SMALL(2),
        MEDIUM(4),
        LARGE(6);
        
        private final int radius;
        PenSize(int radius){this.radius = radius;} 
        
        public int getRadius() {return radius;}
    }
    @FXML private RadioButton blackRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton blueRadioButton;
    @FXML private Button clearButton;
    @FXML private ToggleGroup colorToggleGroup;
    @FXML private Pane drawingAreaPane;
    @FXML private RadioButton greenRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton largeRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton mediumRadioButton;
    @FXML private RadioButton redRadioButton;
    @FXML private ToggleGroup sizeToggleGroup;
    @FXML private RadioButton smallRadioButton;
    @FXML private Button undoButton;
    
    private PenSize radius = PenSize.MEDIUM;
    private Paint brushColor = Color.BLACK;
    
    public void initialize() {
        blackRadioButton.setUserData(Color.BLACK);
        redRadioButton.setUserData(Color.RED);
        greenRadioButton.setUserData(Color.GREEN);
        blueRadioButton.setUserData(Color.BLUE);
        smallRadioButton.setUserData(PenSize.SMALL);
        mediumRadioButton.setUserData(PenSize.MEDIUM);
        largeRadioButton.setUserData(PenSize.LARGE);
    }
    @FXML
    void clearButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        drawingAreaPane.getChildren().clear();
    }

    @FXML
    void colorRadioButtonSelected(ActionEvent event) {
        brushColor = (Color) colorToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData();
    }

    @FXML
    void drawingAreaMouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Circle newCircle = new Circle(e.getX(),e.getY(),radius.getRadius(), brushColor);
        drawingAreaPane.getChildren().add(newCircle);       
    }

    @FXML
    void sizeRadioButtonSelected(ActionEvent event) {
        radius = (PenSize) sizeToggleGroup.getSelectedToggle().getUserData();
    }

    @FXML
    void undoButtonPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        int count = drawingAreaPane.getChildren().size();
        
        if(count>0) {
            drawingAreaPane.getChildren().remove(count-1);
        }
    }

}
```

I want to solve the error.

Comment: Looking at this example https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/fxml_tutorial.htm#CHDIFIAC, I would say you need to prepend the controller class name with the package name in the .fxml file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [_JavaFX FXML controller ClassNotFoundException_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20452035/230513).

Comment: Please don't neglect to cite the original source of example code.